# Issue with Lua Random Number Generation in Loops

Tags: random, lua, numbers

I have a script for a rock-paper-scissors (RPS) game I am making, and I am trying to generate a random number to determine a series of RPS moves. The logic is as follows:

```
moves = {}
table.insert(moves, 'rock')
table.insert(moves, 'paper')
table.insert(moves, 'scissors')

currentMoves = {}

math.randomseed(playdate.getSecondsSinceEpoch()) -- game SDK library function that returns seconds since midnight January 1 2000 UTC to initialize new random sequence
math.random(); math.random(); math.random();


-- generates a list of rps moves to display on the screen
function generateMoves(maxMovesLength) -- i set maxMovesLength to 3

  currentMoves = {}
  for i = 1, maxMovesLength, 1 do
    randomNumber = math.random(1, 3)
    otherRandomNumber = math.random(1,99) -- even with this, based on the presumption 1~33 is rock, 34~66 is paper, 67~99 is scissors, I get a suspicious number of 3 of the same move)
    print(otherRandomNumber)
    table.insert(currentMoves, moves[randomNumber])
  end

  return currentMoves
end
```

However, I noticed that using the Lua math.random() function, I seem to be getting a statistically unlikely number of series of 3 of the same RPS move. The likelihood of getting 3 of the same move (rock rock rock, paper paper paper, or scissors scissors scissors) should be about 11%, but I am getting sets of 3 much more often.

For example, here is what I got when I set maxMovesLength to 15:

```
36 -paper
41 -paper
60 -paper
22 -rock
1 -rock
2 -rock
91 -scissors
36 -paper
69 -scissors
76 -scissors
35 -paper
18 -rock
22 -rock
22 -rock
92 -scissors
```

From this sample, it seems that sets of 3 of a kind are happening much more often than they should be. There are 13 series of 3 moves in this list of 15 moves, and among those 3/13 are three of a kind which would be a probability of about 23%, higher than the expected statistical probability of 11%.

Is this just a flaw in the Lua math library?

Comment: 15 is too small a sample size to test an RNG. I'd go with maybe a million. Also, I calculate the probability of getting 3 of the same result in a row at 1/9, not 10.5%.

Comment: @luther seems you are right on the probability. i was doing .33*.33*.33 cutting off the decimal at 0.035. 

I realize that 15 is a small sample size, but as I am running the game I am also noticing a very high number of sets of 3 of a kind, causing me to think that there might be some issue with math.random()... I'll try a higher number and write a script counting the number of sets of 3.

Comment: Hmm it seems that doing 10000, I get a number that is pretty close to 1100, so I wonder if I am just getting a lot of sets of 3 of a kind initially when the game starts. I have read in other's posts that you need to call math.random() outside of a loop for it to "warm up", whatever that means. Maybe If I call that a lot more before using any of the random numbers it will fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when setting `maxMovesLength` to a very high number this issue doesn't exist, so I will just call `math.random()` a bunch of times before I actually use it in my game (more than the 3 times I currently do under `randomseed()`.